# OnTouch not working in Player class

Tags: java, android, view, ontouch

I am creating a game and would like to read the player input for the character in the characters class. I don't know if this is good practice for game development however it seems like the logical thing to do.

I have the following code within my Player class (relevant code included) however my suspicion is that it isn't working as it isn't the primary view class or something? All help is appreciated.
**Player**

```
public class Player implements View.OnTouchListener{

    private static Player instance = null;

    int x, y;
    boolean moveRight = false;
    Bitmap sprite;

    public Player (Context context){

        sprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.test_sprite);
        x = 300;
        y = 0;
    }

    public void Update(){
        if (moveRight){
            x += 3;
        } else {
            x -= 3;
        }
    }

    public static Player getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new Player(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        float x = motionEvent.getX(), y = motionEvent.getY();
        switch (motionEvent.getAction() & motionEvent.getActionMasked()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                moveRight = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                moveRight = false;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**GameView**

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    private boolean running = true;

    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = getHolder();

    SimpleTurret simpleTurret;
    Player player;

    private Thread thread = new Thread(this);

    public GameView (Context context){
        super(context);

        simpleTurret = SimpleTurret.getInstance(context);
        player = Player.getInstance(context);

        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running){
            DrawCanvas();
            Control();
        }
    }

    public void DrawCanvas(){
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
            canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawBitmap(simpleTurret.getSprite(), simpleTurret.getX(), simpleTurret.getY(), null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(player.getSprite(), player.getX(), player.getY(), null);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    public void Control(){
        try{
            thread.sleep(17);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. The reason why it doesn't work is because your `Player` class is not a View

Comment: So is it standard practice in games development to have the classes that require touch as children of the View class?

Comment: Not necessarily but the `View.onTouchListener` can only be implemented on a View. What is the purpose of the player class? Just implementing the `View.onTouchListener` only provides a function but you need to bind the listener to a View

Comment: I could bind the listener to my GameView class which draws all my sprites to the screen if this is posaible? my player class holds its' own information such as health, speed, x/y location, rect used for collisions, etc. I also want to use it to register player input that is for the player.

Comment: Yeah the onTouchListener would go in the GameView class and then you will bind that to the Views inside them. If you can show that code, then I can maybe help

Comment: I will add my GameView class to the question, thank you.

Comment: Do you want to listen to onTouch of player?

Comment: Yeah, ideally I would like to be able to accept input from the Player class and make decisions in the update method of the player based on the users input.

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, OnTouchListener {

  public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
  } ...
```

`this.setOnTouchListener(this);` line puts the `OnTouchListener` on the `GameView` class which extends the `SurfaceView`. So now anytime there is a touch on your `SurfaceView` the `onTouch` method would be called

Comment: Will I then be able to call onTouch from my player class or will it have to be called through the GameView class as the purpose it to call it from Player.

Comment: No you will receive updates onTouch inside the GameView class and based on that you should update the object `Player`

Comment: I am looking to use GameView purely for rendering the View to the screen, I would be happier creating a view over GameView to take the screen dimentions and pass user input to the relevant classes - Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageView instead a Bitmap and set your implementation of View.OnTouchListener with the method **setOnTouchListener**:

```
ImageView sprite;

public Player (Context context){
    sprite = new ImageView(context);
    sprite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.monkey);
    sprite.setOnTouchListener(this);
    x = 300;
    y = 0;
}
```

Comment: I see how this would work however I am looking to accept touch input from all over the screen rather than just on the player.

Comment: Use setOnTouchListener of your GameView and pass player.


`public GameView (Context context){
        super(context);

        simpleTurret = SimpleTurret.getInstance(context);
        player = Player.getInstance(context);
        this.setOnTouchListener(player);
        thread.start();
    }
`

Comment: I am looking to use GameView purely for rendering the View to the screen, I would be happier creating a view over GameView to take the screen dimentions and pass user input to the relevant classes - Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, you can, but the correct form is use only GameView.

- You do not use onTouch into player Class.
- You have to use onTouch in GameView
- GameView must be match_parent in height and width

Have you heard about **ViewDragHelper**? This can be help you.

[link](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/)